# How do I prevent a word from being auto-corrected?

Tags: autocorrect

This seems kind of obvious but.... if I type in a word that is misspelled and press space, the phone automatically replaces the word with what it thinks is the correct one. How do I prevent this from happening?

If i press backspace and remove the corrected work and retype it incorrectly again, the phone does not correct it the second time around but that is a nuisance. Any other way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to prevent auto-correct just once, tap the text box just after the word you're writing and that should cancel auto-correct.

If you want to undo an auto-correct you just allowed by mistake, tap on the word that changed and the first suggestion should be your original word.

Answer (score 9):

Go to settings > Keyboard > typing settings > tap `language` press to change > uncheck `correct misspelt words`.

Now auto-correct will be turned off entirely. There doesn't seem to be a way to turn of auto-correct for just one word unless you add it into the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

To turn off autocorrect:

1. Settings
2. Keyboard
3. Typing Settings
4. Keyboard Language (has "tap to change" label below it). In my case, it is "English"
5. Uncheck "Correct mispelled words"

Answer (score 1):

> How do I prevent this from happening?

- Settings > Keyboard > Typing Settings > Click on the list of Languages (it says "press to change" beneath it).
- Uncheck "Correct misspelt words".