# How to reject keyboard auto-correction

Tags: keyboard, autocorrect

I like the auto-correct but sometimes I want to reject a specific forced correction. E.g., I like writing "linkedin" (without capitals) but it keeps correcting it to "LinkedIn".

When it corrects me, it writes LinkedIn in bold in the suggestions bar and I don't see how to reject it. Anything I type applies the correction, so I go back to the specific chars and fix them:P

For now, I went into the settings and disabled auto-correct, but I'm looking for a way to reject a single correction.

EDIT - Another clarification:
I want to *reject* a suggested correction when it appears in bold. I did not mean to disable this correction on regular basis, although this could also be an option.

I guess that adding my spelling to the dictionary could have the same effect. I'll try and update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [related question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/59/how-do-i-prevent-a-word-from-being-auto-corrected?rq=1). 
It's not the same on Windows 10 Mobile but here's what I found:

1. Selecting on the word after it was auto-corrected suggests my spelling.
   After choosing my spelling the force-correct for that word appears to be disabled for the current email. I hope it's the same for other document types.
2. Tapping right after the word, before it's corrected, is not a solution in Windows 10 Mobile. It selects a space and the force-correct is still there.
   But tapping in the next line does remove the bold, and the force-correct and then I can bring the cursor (well, caret, really) back to right after the word.
3. I could not find a way to add the word to the dictionary from the email itself, but I could be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the word's case by selecting it and then press the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key on your keyboard. So let your device write "*LinkedIn*", select the word and change the case with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> until you get "*linkedin*". I often use it on my Lumia 1020 because it always suggests "*Smartphone*" instead of "*smartphone*".

Comment: That's a great solution for capitalizing! Unfortunately it doesn't help with misspellings.